# Putting new line in between elements of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array say `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

Now I do a join like give below

```
arr.join("|");
```

My requirement is that this array should contain new line after each third element. Like

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

A help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `array should contain new line after each third element.`?!?!

Comment: So you need to insert the \n char every 5 char in your string

Comment: split into chunks of 3, join each by `|`, and then join the chunks by `\n`? What code have you tried, where was the problem?

Comment: @Hacketo You're assuming the numbers will _always_ be single digits.

Comment: @Brett I'm not assuming, a question like this always give an example that exactly fit the expected solution..

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.join("|").replace(/([^|]+?\|[^|]+?\|[^|]+?)\|/g, "$1\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
i.join('|').replace(/\|/g, function(){
  var c = 0;
  return function(str) {
    return ++c % 3 ? str : '\n';
  }
}());
```

`replace` essentially replaces each third `|` in the string with `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You should slice your array into multiple sub arrays which can individually be joined together:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

// temporary array to push sliced and joined sub array into
var arr_ = [], i;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 3) {
    // slice range of 3 element from arr, join and push into  arr_
    arr_.push(arr.slice(i, i + 3).join("|"));
}

// join by newline
arr_.join("\n");
```

You can extract `3` asvariable to vary the column width.

Answer (score -1):

If you have array of digits:

```
arr.join("|").match(/(\d+\|\d+\|\d+)/g).join("\n");
```